# Exporting artefacts with high detail trimsheet w/ booleans

Tags: modifiers, export, texture-baking, baking

Exporting my high detail trimsheet as an fbx/obj to send to Marmoset for baking, but the output is coming out all whack. I don't know how export writing works, but I guess the result of the triangulation is causing major differences compared to the in-editor model.

https://ibb.co/Z6xc732

[image: Example]

I am using all standard export options. Booleans are done using Bool Tool. Boolean and other helper objects are hidden, I select all, and export using "Only Selected".

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have solved the issue by adding a 'Triangulate' to the end of the modifier stack of any erroneous models. From what I understand every other program is free to triangulate how it wishes, which can be at odds with Blender expectations.

Doesn't seem to have affected how anything looks, I hope this helps someone!